# how to make firebase dashboard

Tags: dashboard

can we create dashboard of firebase data ? without creating any web app for dashboard , can we analyse the data in the firebase dashboard itself .Can any one suggest how it will be possible !

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is NO. What you see in Firebase console is what you get. Firebase is specifically a "serverless" backend for your website which simply provides you with an intuitive API.

**A solution:**
Since it is all Google it is easy to use with Google Apps Script within Google Drive. You could easily write an Apps Script for Google Sheets which connects to your Firebase project and displays the data into a spreadsheet. Then all thats left is up to your imagination. Have fun!

Here are some resources:

- [Apps Script and Firebase](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)
- [Firebase to Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://medium.com/hackernoon/managining-firebase-database-using-google-sheets-via-google-apps-script-b87e5637b006)
- [One more example](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script)